# Proportion of explained variance

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

[image]

I need to find the proportion of explained variance of Y in Model 3. 
Is it correct that I have to find the coefficient of determination? if this is the case then how can I find r squared?

Any help will be appreciated!